# Reusing Code With Database Cursors

Tags: java, android

I find myself using this bit of code very often when I am retrieving the results from a Cursor

```
SearchItem searchItem = new SearchItem();
searchItem.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ID)));
searchItem.setOrigin(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ORIGIN)));
searchItem.setDestination(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_DESTINATION)));
searchItem.setTimeStamp(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP)));
```

Specifically this could be when I am using a `CursorAdapter` for a `ListView` and in a DAO object.

What would be a useful design pattern to use in this case?

My first instinct is to have a singleton class which does this. Are there any problems in taking this route?

Comment: I see I was voted down. I am always open to hear why this is a bad question

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps the voter believed that this type of question leads to discussions of "equally-right" answers, which is discouraged by SO (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I didn't realise it was one of those questions. Maybe I should try something and post on codereview

Comment: Is those five lines **exactly** the same when you write them?

Comment: yes exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure if your question is as easy as it sounds (or if I am missing something), but here's my thought on things.

Using a singleton class for this does not make much sense in my opinion. There's no **state** to be stored, and therefore there's no need for an object at all. Instead, it sounds like you could put it in an utility method.

```
public static SearchItem createSearchItem(Cursor cursor) {
    SearchItem searchItem = new SearchItem();
    searchItem.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ID)));
    searchItem.setOrigin(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ORIGIN)));
    searchItem.setDestination(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_DESTINATION)));
    searchItem.setTimeStamp(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP)));
    return searchItem:
}
```